# Intuit Partner Platform - Unauthorized access issue using production OAuth credentials

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

We're just going live with the Intuit API feature on our live application. We finished the last step of the process by uploading the X.509 certificate signed by Comodo PositiveSSL CA. Though our production access status shows up as ready now, we are having a problem using the production OAUTH credentials. We get an unauthorized exception using these credentials. The development OAUTH credentials work fine though. We also tried using Thawte SSL 123 but no luck even with that.

Also, the actual expiry date of the X.509 certificate, we uploaded is 16-Mar-2014 but when we upload this to the Intuit settings page, it shows expired (0/1/1). Please advice.

Comment: Working with this developer directly through the Intuit Support.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the update here to this question- issue was with pointing to the wrong PFX file.